# Moving the table caption

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

I want to move a wrapped table and caption, I'm trying to use vspace but it doesn't move the caption. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{7cm} \small
  \vspace{-60pt}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll} \hline
A & B  & C\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
  \vspace{-60pt}
  \caption{Caption}
  \vspace{-60pt}
\end{wraptable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please edit your code. It is not compilable because it's missing `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to move the tabular? it is exactly at the beginning of the paragraph:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{7cm} \small
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{lll} \hline
A & B  & C\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the table to start before the beginning of the paragraph. I can move the table up but I can't move the caption up

Comment: a `wraptable` is used to be _inside_  a paragraph. If you want it outside then use a simple right aligned minipage.